# Find problems in Android XML

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I am facing the typical `cannot resolve symbol R` problem in Android Studio after moving some Class and XML files to a new `com.android.library` module from my main `com.android.application` module.

I tried already to `Invalidate Caches/Restart` and `Cleaning/Rebuilding` my project several times. I also deleted the .iml files of my project and restarted Android Studio.

Nothing has worked so far and I can't seem to find any specific pointer to the actual error. I think it should be an XML problem as it is often the case.

Is there a way to check the XMLs for errors in a more systematic way than opeing all the files and copy editing them line by line? The `Messages Gradle Build` window is not showing any XML conflict.

As an extra, one interesting thing is that Android Studio recognizes some of the references to XML resources, even in this broken state.

In this case it is recognizing a resource linked from a different module referenced in Java even if the R class is not recognized nor imported:

[image: Java problem]

In this case, it is recognizing a string resource on the same module in XML:

[image: XML problem]

Could it be an issue with Android Studio itself?

Comment: I have to admit i had similar problem. I just didn't know how to phrase it into a proper looking question. Sometimes i need to add static import for the resources to recognize strings. I believe i was dealing with some toast message and it would throw me an error. After adding static import all was good, but i still don't know what is the problem. If someone helps out it would be awesome, because i would like to know how stuff works "under the hood"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to check the XMLs for errors in a more systematic way than opeing all the files and copy editing them line by line?

You could try analysing the code with Lint. Maybe analyse the whole project in case it's not actually an xml problem, although it often is with R errors. Right click project -> Analyse -> Inspect Code

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint.html

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio 3.3.2 Go To Tools> XML ACTIONS > VALIDATE 
Its redirects to the xml in which you making mistake.

Comment: `Error:External resource http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android is not registered` I got this error. Anyidea?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this is an XML error. Make sure you import "R" in the file that is using it. It is usually something like import (your package name).R

Example from one of my own projects:

```
import com.okdothis.R
```

Comment: Thanks. I already tried with import my.package.name.R , but this is not working.

Comment: Explicit imports like these aren't required when the activity is in the same package as the R class